# Journey Builder sales force data entry for Updates not working

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to use the "Sales Force data" as the entry point to our journey. This is the first time I am exploring this option using the Marketing cloud "Salesforce Data" connector in journey builder.

We need to capture Updates of Contacts in the sales cloud and trigger some action. So we configured the data entry point - Object chosen Contact. Chose Contact Id for "Select who to inject into the journey". Added. Choose the option to capture "Is Updated" and for our criteria chose Lat Modified Date greater then April 1st 2020. Added all contact fields we needed in the Data Extension and saved.

I can confirm that the data extension was created successfully. The journey was activated successfully.

I go to sales force sales and updated the contacts by changing the phone number or Address related fields and save. However I do not see the data flow into the marketing cloud data extension.

If I try the journey with entry point data source Contact inserted - it is successful.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks
Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got help from sales force support - The records we were trying to modify already had a last update date greater than the one set in our criteria. We have to work around this by handling an update scenario in the journey design and creating a synchronized data - to sync contact/account objects in salesforce with marketing cloud every 15 minutes